# Web Service seems to time out 1min before responding

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, web-services, iis

So I have a .NET web service running and when i debug locally and run the service local to my machine a request takes ~4s. However when i push the project to my web server, the exact same request now takes ~1m. I feel as if the request should only take ~5s. I am not sure what I have set wrong.

Here are my fiddler results:

Server Performance:

```
ACTUAL PERFORMANCE
--------------
ClientConnected:           11:21:33.443
ClientBeginRequest:       11:21:42.412
ClientDoneRequest:       11:21:42.412
Gateway Determination: 0ms
DNS Lookup:                 0ms
TCP/IP Connect:                        0ms
HTTPS Handshake:        0ms
ServerConnected:           11:21:13.506
FiddlerBeginRequest:     11:21:42.412
ServerGotRequest:      11:21:42.412
ServerBeginResponse:            11:22:47.085
ServerDoneResponse:    11:22:47.101
ClientBeginResponse:    11:22:47.101
ClientDoneResponse:     11:22:47.101
```

~ 1m05s

Local Performance:

```
ACTUAL PERFORMANCE
--------------
ClientConnected:           11:35:50.111
ClientBeginRequest:       11:35:59.533
ClientDoneRequest:       11:35:59.533
Gateway Determination: 0ms
DNS Lookup:                 0ms
TCP/IP Connect:                        0ms
HTTPS Handshake:        0ms
ServerConnected:           11:35:48.845
FiddlerBeginRequest:     11:35:59.533
ServerGotRequest:      11:35:59.533
ServerBeginResponse:            11:36:03.283
ServerDoneResponse:    11:36:03.298
ClientBeginResponse:    11:36:03.298
ClientDoneResponse:     11:36:03.298
```

~4s

Is this an IIS problem? The web service is calling a ClearQuest API but when i run on the web server directly, there is no issue making a ClearQuest request so I have ruled that out as a bottleneck.

Really stuck here. Appreciate the help.

EDIT 1: I have traced on major lag to here:

```
System.Web.Services.Asmx Information: 0 : Return from IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest
Caller: System.Web.Services.Protocols.SyncSessionlessHandler#19197163::ProcessRequest()
ProcessId=4740
LogicalOperationStack=
ThreadId=5
DateTime=2011-12-19T21:21:36.2218996Z
Timestamp=58279486569830475
System.Web.Services.Asmx Information: 0 : Calling IHttpHandlerFactory.GetHandler
    Caller: System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandlerFactory#50757320::GetHandler()
    Request Host Address: 192.168.5.15
    Request Host Name: itdotnet.kns.com
    Request Url: [POST] http://myurl.com/websvc/CQAccess.asmx
    ProcessId=5348
    LogicalOperationStack=
    ThreadId=6
    DateTime=2011-12-19T21:22:25.7834480Z
    Timestamp=58279635279292073
```

Notice the time stamp is about ~49s

Comment: Try doing a performance trace in both applications if you can, and you'll hopefully find what is going slower than it should

Comment: By doing something like this?
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb885203%28v=VS.90%29.aspx

I ran fiddler and saw this :ServerGotRequest: 11:21:42.412 ServerBeginResponse: 11:22:47.085

Not sure what that means though.

Comment: Yes and also try using DotTrace from jetbrains.com if you can

Comment: Alright ive updated with some data where a significant lag seems to be coming from. Im not sure what to take from it.

Answer (score 0):

When I have run into an issue like this, it was due to a timeout that ocurred during an automatic **certificate revocation** check being performed by the server. This could happen in your server environment if you are using one or more signed (or self-signed) assemblies, or are binding services via SSL with either a self-signed certificate, or perhaps a server behind a proxy or without internet access.

This blog documents the problem fairly well:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/andreal/archive/2008/07/19/wcf-service-startup-too-slow-have-you-thought-to-crl-check.aspx

In my case, the best approach was to switch to a production server with a trusted third-party signed certificate. In other environments I have had to disable certificate revocation and implicitly trust the publisher certificates and all the service endpoint's server certificates.

If the above does not lead to an answer to your question, then this article may provide some other resources to look into:

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/114132/WCF-First-Call-Slow